# If $n=m.p^a$ where $p$ Is a prime and $p$ does not divide m

Tags: sylow-theory

Then ${n \choose p^a} \equiv m \pmod p$. I have read the original textbook proof but I still don't fully understand. Can somebody give me an explicit proof?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-452.pdf

Comment: I don't know how to solve it either, but one observes $\binom{n}{p^a}$ is the number of subsets containing $p^a$ elements in the group of order $n = m p^a$. Maybe we can then proceed using this idea.